# Php: array function with fopen/fread

Tags: php, function, include, fopen, fread

I'm new to php so please bear with me here. 
Its a rough example but lets say I have a file (which obviously does't work :), say `1.php`, there I have

```
<?php 
function links1($l1, $l2){echo "<a href='". $l1 ."'><img src='". $l2 ."'/></a>";}
$ext_file = '2.php';
$v1 = fopen($ext_file, 'r');
$data = fread($v1, filesize($ext_file));
//i assume some piece of code has to go here?? Or maybe i need a new approach ...
?>
```

where I'm trying to basically read 2.php where I have

```
links1("gg1", "1.jpg");
links1("gg2", "2.jpg");
etc...
```

so that when I open 1.php I would see 1.jpg 2.jpg etc etc... How to do that?

And if its possible, how should I modify the code that I could only put

```
gg1 1.jpg
gg2 2.jpg
gg3 3.jpg
gg4 4.jpg
....
```

and it would still work?

Thank you guys for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible...

```
$data = file_get_contents('2.php');
$data = explode("\n", $data);
foreach($data as $string){
    list($l1, $l2) = explode(' ', $string);
    links1($l1, $l2);
}
```

If your line end of line is set to Windows and not UNIX they use `"\r\n"`...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) 2.php inside 1.php.

```
<?php 
function links1($l1, $l2){echo "<a href='". $l1 ."'><img src='". $l2 ."'/></a>";}
include "2.php";
?>
```

2.php should look like:

```
<?php
links1("gg1", "1.jpg");
links1("gg2", "2.jpg");
```

There are 4 different types of include:

- [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) - include a file, don't error if the file exists (but it does throw a warning).
- [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) - include a file, throw an error if the file does not exist.
- [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) - include a file only if it has not been previously included.
- [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) - include a file only if it has not been previously required.

Comment: That doesn't work. It only outputs what it sees in 2.php. So when I open 1.php in the browser I see links1("gg1", "1.jpg");
links1("gg2", "2.jpg");

Comment: 2.php should also have an opening PHP tag so it gets executed.  See my edits.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Now how would I go about making 2.php look gg1 1.jpg
gg2 2.jpg
gg3 3.jpg
gg4 4.jpg
....